# unable to show the approvers names and approval dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

I'm using the approval Workflow from Sharepoint 2010. Every time a new document is created in the folder the workflow starts the approval to a group of people so that any of them can Accept or Reject the request.

I would like to display the user who approved it or rejected it and the date it was approved inside the document in the signature field. Is it possible to do it?

When I check the workflow history I notice that information is already in there (user and date of approval) but I would like the document to be updated by printing the name and date as an approval.

Your support is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get the details of the user who approves the task.

After the approval process start stage, when you try to get the **Task:Assigned To** , you will get the details of the user who approves the current task.

Refer below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work